# Unable to find Checkbox element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

[image: Target Checkbox]

This is the HTML code of the Checkbox alone:

```html
<table id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True" border="0">
   <tbody><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_0" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$0"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_0">Cracked Case</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_1" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$1"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_1">Cracked Case (Upper Half)</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_2" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$2"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_2">Cracked Face Plate</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_3" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$3"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_3">Deep Scratches</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_4" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$4"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_4">Discolored Case</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_5" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$5"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_5">Light Scratches In Case</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_6" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$6"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_6">Major Cracks</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_7" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$7"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_7">Major Scratches</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_8" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$8"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_8">Minor Cracks</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_9" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$9"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_9">Minor Scratches</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_10" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$10"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_10">Missing Port Cover</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_11" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$11"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_11">Missing Side Panel</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_12" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$12"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_12">No Back Cover</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_13" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$13"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_13">No Bay Cover</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_14" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$14"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_14">No Face Plate</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_15" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$15"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_15">Open Box</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_16" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$16"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_16">Open Box, Sealed Unit</label></td><td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_17" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$17"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_17">Scratches In Screen</label></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><input id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_18" type="checkbox" name="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True$18"><label for="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38788_24582_73_0_True_18">Sealed Box</label></td><td></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Hello everyone! the problem is simple and complicated at the same time, in the pictures is my target to click, a checkbox which by all means should be easy to target but for some reason Python keeps throwing me this error (Which i encountered before but right now i can't bypass it):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\Add Asset.py", line 167, in <module>
    nobackcover = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38774_24566_73_0_True_12"]')
  File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38774_24566_73_0_True_12"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Or variations if i am using name or id to target the checkbox.

When i copy the xpath after inspect element with Chrome developer
tools this is what i get:

```
"//*[@id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38760_24576_73_0_True_12"]".
```

This is the code i am using currently:

```
#Here i open the checkbox menu that gives me the checkbox i need to click
Cosmeticselect = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_btnAdd"]')
Cosmeticselect.click()
#2 seconds delay because it takes a second to load.
time.sleep(2)
#I have tried several iterations of this none give me the desire output, maybe this checkbox is in another iframe? if so i have yet to find it in the code.
nobackcover = browser.find_element_by_id('rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38776_24568_73_0_True_12')
#nobackcover = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38775_24567_73_0_True"]/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/label')
#nobackcover = browser.find_element_by_name('rmaAssetCosmeticComponents$ctl00$CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38778_24570_73_0_True$12')
nobackcover.click()
```

I suspect that i have to switch to the cosmetics "window" but i have yet to find a reference to an iframe or the like, i will keep working on it and when i find i solution i will post it but if anyone is interested in adding a fresh pair of eyes to this problem i would appreciate it.

Comment: No offense, but my eyes are not "fresh" anymore after looking on the screenshot and the code :) Please leave only relevant part of the code in the question. Also, what if you right click element in developer tools and copy xpath - what do you get? Thanks.

Comment: And also let us know, element id attribute value is dynamically changing here or fixed??

Comment: Updated the question. Surabh Gaur the element i think is fixed but i am not certain when i know for sure ill update question.

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML code?? And please make sure I'd is fixed or not just refreshing page multiple time and see id is changing or not??

Comment: It would be interesting to see the entire html for the input.I am sure you cane find some distinct string in an attribute the you can use.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Check documentation for wait http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you update with the html code you can try these:

css
`input[id*='rmaAssetCosmeticComponents'][id*='True_12']`

xpath's
`//input[text()='No Back Cover']` or 
`//input[contains(@id, 'rmaAssetCosmeticComponents')][contains(@id, 'True_12')]`

Hopping that the last part of the id does not change, you can create a selector based on the parts of ht attribute that are not changing, or based on the text contained in the element.

Comment: Updated Question.

Comment: Seems that the middle part of the id might change, updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you so much lauda, i swore that it was a static id, thanks for correcting me! Finally with that my script is complete!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your path `(//[@id="rmaAssetCosmeticComponents_ctl00_CheckBoxList_Comp_17_38774_24566_73_0_True_12")` can pointed to correct element by using Selenium IDE

Second, use WebElement wait until the element is clickable or presence Of Element located

Comment: How do i use WebElement to wait for a clickable element? Because until now i have been using "Hard sleeps" to wait for 1 or 3 seconds.